# Interchange of integral and differentiation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistical-inference

**Exercise.**

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n (n\ge 2)$  be  $n$ sample from exponential distribution $\textrm{Exp}(\frac{1}{\theta})$,where $\theta=\mathbb{E}X.$Show that $\bar{X}$ is the UMVUE of $\theta.$

**Solution.**

Let $\mathcal{U}_{0}$ be the class of all unbiased estimators $\varphi$ of 0, that is,
$\mathcal{U}_{0}:=\left\{\varphi:\mathbb{E}_\theta\varphi=0,\mathbb{E}_\theta\varphi^{2}<\infty,\text{for all} \quad\theta\in \Theta \right\},$ where $ \Theta=\left ( 0，\infty \right ).$
$$\mathbb{E}_\theta\varphi=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{0}^{\infty}\varphi(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n})\cdot\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left\{ \frac{1}{\theta} \exp\left (-\frac{x_i}{\theta}  \right )\right\}dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n=0.$$
${\color{Red}{\text{Taking the derivative with respect to }}}$${\color{Red}\theta}$ ${\color{Red}{\text{from above equation}}}$, we have
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{n\bar{x}}{\theta^2}\cdot\varphi(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n})\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{\theta}\right)dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n=0.$$
Then $$\text{Cov}_{\theta}\left (\bar{X}, \varphi\right )=\mathbb{E}_\theta \left ( \bar{X}\cdot\varphi \right )=0,\forall \varphi\in \mathcal{U}_{0},\forall \theta\in \Theta. $$
Therefore, $\bar{X}$ is the UMVUE of $\theta.$

---

Why can we directly exchange integral and differentiation? This needs some rigorous explanations.
Is there an integrable $Y(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ such that $$\left|\frac{n\bar{x}}{\theta^2}\cdot\varphi(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n})\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{\theta}\right) \right|\le Y $$ almost surely  for all $\theta\in \Theta=\left ( 0，\infty \right ) ?$

Comment: You can assume $\theta\in(a,b)\subset(0,\infty)$ and take $$Y(x_1,\ldots,x_n):=\frac{n\bar x}a^2\cdot\lvert\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\rvert\cdot\exp\!\left(-\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}b\right)\!.$$ (I let you check that $\int_0^\infty Y(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,\mathrm dx_1\cdots\mathrm dx_n<\infty$.)

Comment: Try with Cauchy−Schwarz inequality. *Hint.* You know that $\Bbb E_{b}\varphi^2<\infty$…

Comment: @nejimban I ignored the condition $\mathbb{E}_\theta\varphi^{2}<\infty$.Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed we just need $\varphi $ integrable. We have an expression of the form
$$
\int_{[0,\infty )^n} \varphi (\mathbf{x})\theta ^{-n}e^{-\frac{\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{1}}{\theta }}\,d \mathbf{x}=\theta ^{-n}\int_{[0,\infty )^n} \varphi (\mathbf{x})e^{-\frac{\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{1}}{\theta }}\,d \mathbf{x}\tag1
$$
for $\mathbf{x}:=(x_1,\ldots,x_n )$ and $\mathbf{1}:=(1,\ldots ,1)$. Also, without lose of generality, we can assume that $\varphi \geqslant 0$ and that $\mu(d\mathbf{x}):=\varphi (\mathbf{x})\,d \mathbf{x}$ is a probability measure. Therefore, by Tonelli's theorem, the question is reduced to show that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta }\int_{[0,\infty )} e^{-x/\theta }\mu(d x)=\int_{[0,\infty )} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta }e^{-x/\theta }\mu(dx)\tag2
$$
Now let $f$ be the integrand of the LHS of (2), then for any neighborhood $U:=(\theta _0-\epsilon ,\theta _0+\epsilon)$ of $\theta _0$ where $\epsilon \in(0,\theta _0/2)$ by the mean value theorem we have that
$$
\left| \frac{f(x,\theta_0 +h)-f(x,\theta_0 )}{h} \right|\leqslant \sup_{\theta \in U}\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta }f(x,\theta)\right|\leqslant g(x)\tag3
$$
for $g(x):=(\theta _0-\epsilon )^{-2} xe^{-x/(\theta _0+\epsilon )}$ and all $|h|\leqslant \epsilon $. As $g$ doesn't depend on $\theta $ and its integrable, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to show that (2) holds.∎